# How can I force all my facebook tokens to expire without using the command line?

Tags: facebook, api, token

I'm sure I could figure out how to do this on the command line if I spent my entire morning looking ...but it's not my comfort zone.

I know I can revoke app access, but I need some of those apps. So, I just want to expire access everywhere.

Context: I got logged out (had my token expired by FB) but afterwards I got a verification request from an outside app that I didn't request for App Kit access. I don't want any apps using my credentials to do their dirty work on Facebook.

Comment: just change your password, that should expire all tokens

Comment: @luschn ...and that works for any api tokens that "I" have requested as well?

Comment: ^that have been requested from my account, that is.

Comment: only you can authorize apps with your account, no one else. and the tokens generated with that authorization can be invalidated by changing the facebook password.

Comment: Right, but I was one of the people who's token was reset. Meaning that somebody else was using my account for a while. And it seems to me that if I got a request for verification from App Kit that they still had a way to request access from my account.

Comment: if you talk about that thing from facebook where a lot of people got logged out...that does not mean someone had YOUR access tokens, it was just a precaution. and again: tokens get invalidated by changing your facebook password.

Comment: Any idea why Account Kit by Facebook sent me a verification code to complete access by an outside app that I didn't request then?

Comment: BTW, I didn't change my password after the forced token expiration, but I did change it just now.

Comment: an outside app you did not authorize? well, if it is not even in your list in the settings, ignore it, i would say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180995/discussion-between-pixelfairy-and-luschn).

Comment: to be honest, this does not really look like a question that is programming related, which is what stackoverflow is about. this is basically user support for facebook, right?

Comment: If the question was "how can I use other people's tokens to write apps on the fb api" would it be programming related?

Comment: that question would not even make any sense...;) - tokens to write apps? what? anyway, you are not allowed to use other peoples tokens if those tokens don´t belong to your own app - or without the approval of users. "how can i do something that is not allowed" is not really in the scope of stackoverflow, obviously ;)